# Storing the node degrees of a group of networks in an excel sheet

Tags: r, igraph

I have a code that creates multiple random graphs in R using the igraph package.

```
set.seed(1)
gs1 <- list()
for (x in seq_len(500L)) 
{
  gs1[[x]] <- sample_bipartite(62, 243, type = "gnm",m = 630, directed = TRUE)

}
```

I know how to individually retrieve the node degrees of each graph.

```
degree(gs1[[1]], v = V(gs1[[1]]), mode = c("all", "out", "in", "total"),
+        loops = TRUE, normalized = FALSE)
```

As you can see, I have created 500 random networks with those values. I would like to store the node degrees of all 500 of these networks in an excel sheet (hopefully 500 columns in a single sheet). How can I do so? Kindly advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply

```
write.csv(sapply(gs1, degree), file = "degrees.csv")
```

will do the job. It will be a 305x500 table.

Also, in your case there is no need to write `loops`, etc. because your parameter values are default. Also, only one/the first value of `mode` is considered, so perhaps you should take another look at `?degree` as to make sure what kind of degree you want.